# OAuth v2 no Django 1.4

Tags: python, django, oauth2, pycharm

Amigos, estou estudando como implementar o protocolo OAuth v2 na minha aplicação. Já pesquisei muito aqui e não encontrei nada que pudesse resolver meu problema. Até o momento tenho um banco de dados no PostgreSQL e autenticação com uma middleware do Django.

Venho tentando seguir a documentação em http://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/, sem sucesso, porque o PyCharm não reconhece o algumas bibliotecas em **INSTALLED_APPS** e outras coisas fundamentais nesse tutorial que em teoria tem suporte ao Django 1.4.x.

Teriam como me ajudar, por favor?

**Informações**:

- Ambiente: PyCharm 2016.2.3
- Interpretador: Python 2.7.12
- Framework: Django 1.4.22
- Banco de dados: PostgreSQL 9.3.15
- Sistema Operacional: Windows 7 - 32 bits

Comment: Só por curiosidade, você está usando django 1.4 por alguma imposição de um cliente ou simplesmente por que quer?

Comment: Na documentação que você citou, essa biblioteca não suporta a versão 1.4 do django.

Comment: É uma necessidade do cliente. Tem uma versão dessa documentação que diz que suporta: http://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. Alterei na pergunta!

Answer (score 1):

Se o pycharm não esta reconhecendo as bibliotecas, significa que o seu projeto pode estar apontando para um ambiente diferente de onde estão instaladas essas bibliotecas, veja na configuração:

File/setings/Project:seuprojeto/Project Interpreter

Veja a figura[image: Configuração Pycharm]